# Why doesn't this callback return a value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, callback, arcgis

```
gsvc.project(params, function (projectedPoints) {
    pt = projectedPoints[0];
});

geometry.addPath(pt);
```

Can anyone tell me why `projectedPoints` only returns once an error is thrown? The code doesn't enter the callback and tries to assign pt while it is undefined to an array. This causes the code to error, which is when the callback finally initiates.

I've been trying to reference the code from [here](http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/samples/util_project/), but can't seem to figure out how to get the callback to work like in the xample.

`
    
      var map, gsvc, pt;

```
  require([
    "esri/map", "esri/graphic", "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol",
    "esri/tasks/GeometryService", "esri/tasks/ProjectParameters",
    "esri/SpatialReference", "esri/InfoTemplate", "dojo/dom", "dojo/on",
    "dojo/domReady!"
  ], function(
    Map, Graphic, SimpleMarkerSymbol,
    GeometryService, ProjectParameters,
    SpatialReference, InfoTemplate, dom, on
  ) {
    map = new Map("map", {
      basemap: "streets",
      center: [-98.445, 46.147],
      zoom: 3
    });

    gsvc = new GeometryService("http://tasks.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer");
    map.on("click", projectToWebMercator);

    function projectToWebMercator(evt) {
      map.graphics.clear();

      var point = evt.mapPoint;
      var symbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol().setStyle("diamond");
      var graphic = new Graphic(point, symbol);
      var outSR = new SpatialReference(102100);

      map.graphics.add(graphic);

      gsvc.project([ point ], outSR, function(projectedPoints) {
        pt = projectedPoints[0];
        graphic.setInfoTemplate(new InfoTemplate("Coordinates",
          "<span>X:</span>" + pt.x.toFixed() + "<br>" + 
          "<span>Y:</span>" + pt.y.toFixed() + "<br>" + 
          "<input type='button' value='Convert back to LatLong' id='convert'>" +
          "<div id='latlong'></div>"));
        map.infoWindow.setTitle(graphic.getTitle());
        map.infoWindow.setContent(graphic.getContent());
        map.infoWindow.show(evt.screenPoint, map.getInfoWindowAnchor(evt.screenPoint));
        on.once(dom.byId("convert"), "click", projectToLatLong);
      });
    }

    function projectToLatLong() {
      var outSR = new SpatialReference(4326);
      var params = new ProjectParameters();
      params.geometries = [pt.normalize()];
      params.outSR = outSR;

      gsvc.project(params, function(projectedPoints) {
        pt = projectedPoints[0];
        dom.byId("latlong").innerHTML = "<span>Latitude: </span> " + 
          pt.y.toFixed(3) + "<br><span>Longitude:</span>" + pt.x.toFixed(3);
      });
    }
  });
</script>`
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a variable scope issue. `pt` needs to be defined outside your callback.

```
var pt;

gsvc.project(params, function(projectedPoints) {
    pt = projectedPoints[0];
});

geometry.addPath(pt);
```

**EDIT:**

If the `.project()` method is asynchronous, then Arun's answer is the correct approach.

Comment: Then it's most likely asynchronous. Try moving the last line inside the callback like Arun suggested.

Comment: I've tried that also. It still skips and just fails further down in the code

Comment: That's odd. Is the callback being executed? Try throwing a `console.log()` in there.

Comment: It executes, using chrome developer tools I can see the request being made, but the response just hangs there until the code errors out, it's until then the callback actually executes

Comment: In that case, I think we'll need to see more of your code to help you. Also, what was the error you mentioned?

Comment: The error usually will happen when an undefined array is called. Once it fails, that's when the callback will return the values. @Stuart

Answer (score 0):

It might be because project is a async method if so

```
//looks like project is a async method
gsvc.project(params, function (projectedPoints) {
    var pt = projectedPoints[0];
    //do all operations which depends on pt in the callback
    geometry.addPath(pt);
});

//so this part will get executed before the callback is executed so pt won't be defined
```

- [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call) - it follows the same principle as ajax requests

Comment: The function gets skipped and errors further down the code before returning to the callback

Comment: @David that is why all code that depends on value returned by the callback must be inside the callback.. if you can share more details about the code we can have a look

Comment: I updated the original post to include an example of what I'm trying to accomplish @Arun